# Magento router 404

Tags: controllers, module, router

The rest of my module is working correctly.  This is for a custom payment method.  I have the module enabled.  I can see the custom payment method in System > Configuration > Payment Methods as well as in the checkout.  I keep getting a 404 when trying to access the page though:

```
site.com/store/heartland
site.com/store/heartland/index
site.com/store/heartland/index/hello
```

Module Directory:

```
Company/Heartland$ ls
controllers/
etc/
Helper/
Model/
sql/
```

Controller Directory:

```
Company/Heartland$ ls controllers/
IndexController.php
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
            <Company_Heartland>
                    <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Company_Heartland>
    </modules>
    <global>
            <models>
                    <heartland>
                            <class>Company_Heartland_Model</class>
                    </heartland>
            </models>
        <helpers>
          <heartland>
            <class>Company_Heartland_Helper</class>
          </heartland>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <default>
            <payment>
                    <heartland>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <active>0</active>
                            <model>heartland/paymentMethod</model>
                            <order_status>pending</order_status>
                            <title>Credit Card (Heartland)</title>
                            <cctypes>AE,VI,MC,DI</cctypes>
                            <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
                            <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                    </heartland>
            </payment>
    </default>
    <frontend>
            <routers>
                    <heartland>
                            <use>standard</use>
                            <args>
                                    <module>Company_Heartland</module>
                                    <frontname>heartland</frontname>
                            </args>
                    </heartland>
            </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Company_Heartland_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    // The redirect action is triggered when someone places an order
    public function helloAction() {

            echo "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section that is a problem is in you config.xml when defining the router. This is because `frontName` is case sensitive and so should be as follows:

```
<frontName>heartland</frontName>
```